# session_start в slow-log

Tags: php, сессия, php-fpm

Сервер стал лагать и я включил `slow log s php-fpm`. При анализе лога тысячи вот таких записей:

```
[07-Nov-2015 22:37:05]  [pool www-php-fpm-default] pid 23718
script_filename = /home/www-php-fpm-default/www/site.ru/index.php
[0x00007f622982f518] session_start() /home/www-php-fpm-default/www/site.ru/index.php:2
```

Искал ответ в гугле, ничего, кроме `session_write_close()` не нашёл. Почему session_start тормозит сервер?

Comment: так а в чём, собственно, заключается *вопрос*?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, почему session_start тормозит сервер

Comment: 1. внесите это, пожалуйста, в вопрос, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса. 2. по-моему, на основании приведённых данных можно лишь гадать на кофейной гуще.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin на самом деле нет, сейчас соберусь и накатаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле это (*скорее всего*) классическая проблема. В PHP встроен блокирующий режим работы с сессиями. Сессии хранятся как обычные файлы в каком-нибудь `/var/lib/php5`, и когда php-процесс открывает этот файл, он ставит на него *лок*. Это значит, что пока поставивший лок php-процесс жив и не снял лок, все остальные процессы, которые попытаются открыть файл на запись, будут остановлены и будут ждать, пока этот лок не будет снят. Таким образом, два одновременных запроса к веб-приложению со стандартным обработчиком сессий будут выполняться последовательно - первый придет и откроет файл сессии, заблокировав его, а второй бует ждать, пока блокировка не кончится. Скорее всего, именно это и является причиной длительного выполнения `session_start()` - процесс просто ждет, когда он наконец сможет получить доступ к сессии. Блокировка там выставляется неспроста - это самый простой способ обеспечить невозможность записи значений более раннего запроса поверх значений более позднего (во время тех же двух одновременных запросов, например), поэтому в случае, если вы решите сменить обработчик сессий, стоит дополнительно задуматься над возможностью такого сценария (и, возможно, защититься тем же способом).

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ! Но что нужно сделать, что-бы проблема решилась?

Comment: @ВладимирМарков, я же написал, это не проблема как таковая. Это способ защиты целостности данных путем предотвращения конкуррентного доступа, чтобы в сесси не оказалось неожиданных данных. Как и то, что можн опоставить другой хендлер сессии, который не будет блокировать чтение и запись, но внесет возможность нарушения целостности данных.

Comment: сессии в мемкеше хранятся

Comment: @ВладимирМарков это стоило уточнить. Какая библиотека используется? Это может быть либо такое же блокирование, либо, что куда опасней, проблемы с сетью и нагруженностью сервера мемкэша.

Comment: как эта ошибка появилась я пытался решить проблему, перевёл на memcache сессии, проблема не решилась... memcached 1.4.14

Comment: @ВладимирМарков какая библиотека? В чем конкретно сотоит проблема - это осязаемая задержка или нет?